# How to log response times in DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a delegating handler called "PerformanceHandler". I want to log the response times of all requests that come in.

I created a StopWatch and start it in SendAsync, and then return it using:
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith. However, when I try this, all requests seem to never return, and it does not log the time at all.

What am I doing wrong? If this code doesn't make sense, what's the proper way to log the timing of requests in a DelegatingHandler?

**My Global.asax.cs contains:**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new PerformanceHandler());
```

**My PerformanceHandler.cs code:**

```
    public class PerformanceHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Stopwatch", stopwatch));

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Log(request, t.Result);
                return t.Result;
            });

        }

        private void Log(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var requestMethod = request.Method.Method;
            var requestUri = request.RequestUri.ToString();

            var stopwatch = (Stopwatch)request.Properties["Stopwatch"];
            stopwatch.Stop();

            var responseTimeInMilliseconds = 1000; //stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            int userObjectId = UserSession.Current().UserObjectId;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End of Request");

            //LOG TIME HERE
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below modification will work.

```
public class PerformanceHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Stopwatch", stopwatch));

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            Log(request, response);

            return response;

        }
   }
```